# How do I uninstall an app in my Google account?

Tags: google-drive, google-account

I found an unwanted app in my Google Drive nine-dot-icon:

[image]

How do I remove it?

Thanks

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/myapps
   The page will show all the Google Marketplace installed in your account.
2. Click the three dot button on the top-right corner of the app that you want to uninstall, then select Uninstall.